# Writing a custom reduction function in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, iteration, slice

What I want to to:
Let's say I have data in form of a 1D array. After fitting that data, (scipy.optimize.curve_fit), this will be reduces to a skaler/0D array. So far so good. That is the easy part.

The problem is, that the data is not actually in 1D, but (n+1)D. So I will have to iterate over the whole array over all axis but one, take a 1D slice, fit that slice and write this into a new array with n dimensions. For the sake of simplicity I used the sum function instead of fitting in this example code.

```
def iter_columns(array: np.ndarray, axis=-1) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Reduce nd-data to (n-1)d data. By performing the operation on one axis.
    :param array: Input data
    :param axis: Axis to perform reduction over
    :return: Array of reduced data
    """
    reduced_shape = list(array.shape)
    reduced_shape.pop(axis)
    print(reduced_shape)
    a = np.empty(tuple(reduced_shape))
    print(a)
    print(array)
    with np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=[['writeonly']]) as it:
        for a_i in it:
            # modify multi index to slice over dimension of axis, append if axis
            mod = list(it.multi_index)
            mod.insert(axis if axis>=0 else len(mod),slice(None))
            print(mod)
            a_i[...] = b[tuple(mod)].sum()
    return a


b = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
print(iter_columns(b, axis=-1))
```

Although this seems like it does what it is supposed to, it doesn't seem really elegant. I tried using np.nditer in some other ways, though i do not understand how to tell nditer to load chunks instead of  just the single array entry. I am also aware that there is a ufunc.reduce function precisely for this, but I cannot find documentation on how to construct functions that can be used by it.

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general python function, there isn't a fast compiled way of doing this kind of reduction.  Regardless of the iteration mechanism, you end up having to call the `func` once for each of the `nD` set of values.

For `np.sum` you can just specify the `axis`.  This is essentially a `np.add.reduce`.

`np.apply_along_axis` works much like your `nditer`, except it moves the slice dimension to the end, making the 'insert' easier.  And it uses `ndindex` to generate the indexing tuples - but that too uses `nditer`.  It's documentation is wrong; it isn't faster.

Some comparative timings:

```
In [223]: timeit iter_columns(b, axis=-1)
55.2 µs ± 1.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [224]: timeit iter_columns(b, axis=-1)
54.6 µs ± 63.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [225]: timeit np.array([i.sum() for i in b])
40 µs ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [226]: timeit b.sum(-1)
6.86 µs ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Your use of `nditer` is correct (often people have problems with it), but as you can see it doesn't offer any speed advantage.  For higher dimensions, it would just as fast to write multiple loops.

Another way to handle higher dimensions is to move the `sum` axis last, reshape the rest to 1d, and do a simple loop, followed by a reshape.

Another option is to compile your function and loop.  `numba` is a powerful tool for that.  One of the `nditer` doc pages shows how to use `nditer` in `cython`.

Comment: It's interesting, that the list comprehension version seems to be faster than nditer. However this wouldn't be applicable to n-dimensions without flattening and reshaping, right?

np.apply_along_axis seems to do exactly what I did, just much more concise.
However, my code for some reason seems to be performing better for some reason.
´np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 1, b) in 4.783232e-05 s
iter_columns(b, axis=1, func=np.sum) in 2.07615e-05 s´

I have the feeling, that I'm lacking the experience with numba and cython for timely results.

Comment: I don't know why `apply` is slow, except that it has to perform a trial calculation to determine the return `dtype`.  I don't think nested loops are any slower, since it's the total number of `func` calls that matters most.  They look messier, that's all.